# Making clickable hyperlink from URL with QT Creator for QGIS custom forms?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qt-designer

I am creating custom forms for QGIS with QT Creator.
I want to know how to make a clickable hyperlink from an URL.
It is said that QT Creator can handle them directly in a QLabel if the "OpenExternalLinks" and "LinkAccessibleByMouse" features are selected. But I can't manage to get a clickable hyperlink available and working…

Is there a way with a small Python code to force QT to do it?

Or by using a button instead?

Comment: Are you developing a plugin which shows the form or is it a custom attribute form configured in the layer properties?

Comment: It's a custom attribute form configured in the layer properties. Then it is saved in a Geopackage.
The aim is to build good looking forms and easy to use for none GIS users.
The custom form included in QGIS doesn't provide the features I am needing and it's a bit ugly.